# perl help finding proper date format

Tags: perl, datetime, date

I need some help trying to figure out how to format dates in perl. I have a working perl script, with a regular expression, that works fine if I use hard coded date strings like this:

```
my $mon = 'Aug';
my $day = '05';
my $year = '2010';
```

These vars are used in a regular expression like this:

```
if ($line =~ m/(.* $mon $day) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} $year: ([^:]+):backup:/)
```

Now, I need to automate this date portion of the code and use current date systematically.
I looked into perl localtime and tried using unix date and throw them into variables.
I need to have the days of the week, single digit, be padded with '0'. As in today, 'Aug' '05' 
'2010' because the input file I am using for the regex has dates like this.

My 2nd try with the unix and formatting is returning numbers, but I need to have them be strings:

```
 my $mon2=`date '+%b'`;
 my $day2=`date '+%d'`;
 my $year2=`date '+%Y'`;
```

My test code for playing with date formats:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $mon = 'Aug';
my $day = '05';
my $year = '2010';

my $mon2=`date '+%b'`;
my $day2=`date '+%d'`;
my $year2=`date '+%Y'`;

print "$mon";
print "$day";
print "$year";

print "$mon2";
print "$day2";
print "$year2";
```

My Output:

```
Aug052010Aug
05
2010
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but you're reinventing the wheel.  All this is implemented quite comprehensively in the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) distribution and the [DateTime::Format::](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime#Formatters_And_Stringification) family of classes:

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now;
print 'It is currently ', $dt->strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S'), ".\n";
```

prints:

```
It is currently Aug 05 23:54:01.
```

Comment: And if you don't want to install DateTime for some reason (even though it's awesome) you can use the `strftime` function in the standard `POSIX` module.